Pipe with process in c
I am doing minishell, a 42 project where you need to simulate bash. I thought that i could do my execution part as follows

setup the redirections
check if it is a builtin
execute the command

it works when i dont use blocking commands like cat
if i type this
cat | cat | ls 

in bash it will output
Makefile  include  infile  libs  main.c  main.o  minishell  outfile  src
^C

but if i type
cat | cat | ls

in my minishell it will just wait an entry for cat without executing ls
i probably missunderstood something with pipes or process
note that i have to use execve cause my functions are limited by the exercise.
here is how I handle redirections
int setup_redirections(t_command_line *command_line, int *pipe)
{
    int return_value;

    return_value = SUCCESS;
    close(pipe[0]);
    if (command_line->input_file != NULL)
    {
        if (handle_infile(command_line) == FAIL)
            return_value = FAIL;
    }
    if (command_line->output_file != NULL)
    {
        if (handle_outfile(command_line) == FAIL)
            return_value = FAIL;
    }
    else if (command_line->next != NULL)
        dup2(pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipe[1]);
    return (return_value);
}

int handle_infile(t_command_line *command_line)
{
    int return_value;
    int fd_in;

    return_value = SUCCESS;
    if (access(command_line->input_file, F_OK) != 0)
    {
        printf("error while accessing file\n");
        return (FAIL);
    }
    if (access(command_line->input_file, R_OK) != 0)
    {
        printf("error while reading file\n");
        return (FAIL);
    }
    fd_in = open(command_line->input_file, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_in == -1)
    {
        printf("error while opening file\n");
        return_value = FAIL;
    }
    dup2(fd_in, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd_in);
    return (return_value);
}

int handle_outfile(t_command_line *command_line)
{
    int fd_out;

    if (command_line->append_output > 0)
        fd_out = open(command_line->output_file,
                O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0644);
    else
        fd_out = open(command_line->output_file,
                O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fd_out == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EACCES)
            printf("minishell: %s: Permission denied\n",
                command_line->output_file);
        else
            perror("minishell: open failed");
        return (FAIL);
    }
    dup2(fd_out, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd_out);
    return (SUCCESS);
}

void    save_or_restore_fds(t_minishell *minishell, int order)
{
    if (order == SAVE)
    {
        minishell->data->save_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
        minishell->data->save_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    }
    else if (order == RESTORE)
    {
        dup2(minishell->data->save_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(minishell->data->save_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
    }
}

int wait_for_all(pid_t pid)
{
    pid_t wait_pid;
    int status;
    int last_status;

    wait_pid = 0;
    last_status = 0;
    while (wait_pid != -1 || errno != ECHILD)
        {
            wait_pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            if (wait_pid == pid)
                last_status = status;
        }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(last_status) && WTERMSIG(last_status) == SIGPIPE)
        return (0);
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(last_status))
        return (128 + WTERMSIG(last_status));
    else if (WIFEXITED(last_status) && !WIFSIGNALED(last_status))
        return (WEXITSTATUS(last_status));
    return (last_status);
}

Can someone explain me my problem please?
Maybe it comes from my child function

The problem probably isn't with redirection. If you're not seeing ls output, you're not running all the processes concurrently, since ls doesn't use its stdin.

tl;dr (your code that is)... does '(cat | cat | ls) < -' work ?
